# gnu/linux терминал, настроки bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

в процессе настройки одной программы была в статье команда:

```
chsh -s /bin/sh igor
```

выполнил ее (я думаю, что именно из-за нее ), и теперь терминал открыватеся не под юзером.

просто `$` (вверху написано `/bin/sh`).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вернуть назад, чтобы писало юзера, под каким открыт терминал.

**UPD**  добавил скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смените назад на баш `chsh /bin/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы сменили используемый `shell`. можно вернуть его «назад» на `/bin/bash`.

для себя:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```

или указанного пользователя (тут, понятно, понадобится повышение привилегий, если этот пользователь — не вы):

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash пользователь
```

---

`shell` можно загрузить и не таким «кардинальным» способом. всего лишь запустите что-нибудь из списка `/etc/shells`, конечно, если подходящий пакет установлен. например, установив пакет `tcsh`, можно запускать `shell` из него:

```
$ tcsh
%
```

программа будет работать, пока вы её не завершите, и это никак не повлияет на новые `shell`-сессии.

---

чуть больше подробностей можно увидеть, как и обычно, в *man*-страничке:

```
$ man chsh
```